# Show whether it is a stopping time or not.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

> Let $X = \{ X_t\}$ be a stochastic process on $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P)$. Explain briefly why each of the following is or is not a stopping time:

> (c) Let $\{A_j \}_{j=1}^n$ be a sequence of measurable sets, and consider the first time $X$ reaches $A_n$, after first reaching $A_{n-1}$, after first reaching $A_{n-2}$, ... , after first reaching $A_1$.

Let $T_i = \inf \{ t \in \mathbb{T}: X_t \in A_i\}$ such that $T_i \le T_{i+1}$ for all $i$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is a set of time. I have to show that $\{T_n \le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{T}$, where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is a filtration of $\mathcal{F}$. My idea is that: $\{T_n \le t\} = \cup_{j 
 = T_{n-1} }^t X^{-1}_j(A_n)$. Then, $X^{-1}_j(A_n) \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for each $j \le t$.  But I don't know how to deal with $T_{n-1}$ on the subscript here.  Can someone help me?

Comment: You want to first do this for two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ (or for just $A_1$, like the usual hitting time of a set being a stopping time, if that isn't clear). Then you can extend to higher $n$, using induction. The $T_{n-1}$ on the subscript will need you to call upon a suitable induction hypothesis, which you can't formulate until you try this for smaller indices.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I can see that $T_1$ is a stopping time by showing what I describe above. I am trying to do with $A_1$ and $A_2$, but I still face the same problem of dealing with $T_1 \le T_2$.

Comment: Actually, there may be canonical counterexamples if we don't assume something about the stochastic process $X_i$. Even in the usual scenario where $X_t$ is a stochastic process on $\mathbb R$, it is not necessary that a hitting time is a stopping time. Usually some kind of continuity must be imposed on $X_i$ for this to work out. Unless $\mathbb T$ is discrete, in which case I believe things can be worked out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will continue to read and hope to find a relevant counter-example.

Comment: Sure, you can add an answer once you are confident. I expect this to work out for the discrete case via induction, but I can't think of a proof just as yet.